# selenium library is not showing up in pycharm when writing the first script

Tags: python, pycharm

I am beginner to the pycharm selenium, i have to create the first project in selenium but when i am writing the script it is not displaying the inbuilt method whereas when i am running the script through python console it is running and opening the browser.

I have installed the selenium package but when i am running first script in selenium it is able to run and giving error also when i am writing the script it is not displaying the inbuilt method

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("")
driver.**
```

can anybody please help ...

Comment: Can you share the error? These problems usually occur when the Python installation with the library is not the one being used to execute the program.

Answer (score 0):

When you create project in pycharm check selenium module and its submodules present under ..\Lib\site-packages

[image]

Comment: Isn't this only try if they're using venv?

Comment: Selenium lib should be there inside the \Lib\site-packages of python. You can select interpreter using venv while creating your project also it allows to installed lib for a single project

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved